# AlaSQL XLSX fomatting and Styling Issue

Tags: javascript, excel

I'm exporting HTML table data to XLSX the coding working good. But when i'm trying to Export file with formatting and styling file is not generating with styles. Can you tell me how to do this.

Comment: I want to add a dropdown list for the selected column in alasql can you tell me how to achieve that

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
var opts = {
  headers:true, 
  column: {style:{Font:{Bold:"1",Color: "#3C3741"}}},
  rows: {1:{style:{Font:{Color:"#FF0077"}}}},
  cells: {1:{1:{
    style: {Font:{Color:"#00FFFF"}}
  }}}
};
alasql('SELECT * INTO XLSXML("restest280b.xls",?) FROM ?',[opts,data]);
```

Comment: I want to add a dropdown list for the selected column in alasql can you tell me how to achieve that